# How to write into Bitquery table from a text file located at Google Storage?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm new to apache beam and Google cloud dataflow, I want to write a programe using Java SDK to read data from a text file which is located at Google Storage and insert the data into Google Bigquery.

I've written a code for the problem but it shows error `Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up.`

```
public class StarterPipeline {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StarterPipeline.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.setTempLocation("gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp");
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<String> input = p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/emp_details.txt"));

    PCollection<TableRow> output = input.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, TableRow>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c)  {
        StringTokenizer  tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(c.element(),",");
        c.output(new TableRow()
                .set("id", Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()))
                .set("emp_name",tokenizer.nextToken())
                .set("designation", tokenizer.nextToken())
                .set("dob",Date.parseDate(tokenizer.nextToken()))
                .set("contact_no",Long.parseLong(tokenizer.nextToken()))
                .set("location",tokenizer.nextToken())
                .set("salary",Float.parseFloat(tokenizer.nextToken())));
      }
    }));

    String tableSpec = "gcp-training-246913:com_example_gcptraining.employee";
    output.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(tableSpec).withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER).withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
  }
}
```

Please help me resolve the problem.

Thanks !!!

Here is the consol output log,

```
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:47 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource getEstimatedSizeBytes
INFO: Filepattern gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/emp_details.txt matched 1 files with total size 682
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:47 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource split
INFO: Splitting filepattern gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/emp_details.txt into bundles of size 170 took 67 ms and produced 1 files and 4 bundles
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:48 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads$4 getTempFilePrefix
INFO: Writing BigQuery temporary files to gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/ before loading them.
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:49 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowWriter <init>
INFO: Opening TableRowWriter to gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/57558a8c-977e-478d-a44c-7863fb230af2.
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:49 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowWriter <init>
INFO: Opening TableRowWriter to gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5.
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:49 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowWriter <init>
INFO: Opening TableRowWriter to gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d73bb64e-cced-4016-9529-12df5bed8b9e.
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:49 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowWriter <init>
INFO: Opening TableRowWriter to gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/be562c41-3aee-4c98-b1de-3e10691e3454.
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:50 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Loading 4 files into {datasetId=com_example_gcptraining, projectId=gcp-training-246913, tableId=employee} using job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-0, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913}, attempt 0
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:50 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl startJob
INFO: Started BigQuery job: {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-0, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913}.
bq show -j --format=prettyjson --project_id=gcp-training-246913 beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-0
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:50 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Load job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-0, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} started
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:51 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl pollJob
INFO: Still waiting for BigQuery job beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-0, currently in status {"state":"RUNNING"}
bq show -j --format=prettyjson --project_id=gcp-training-246913 beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-0
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:52 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl pollJob
INFO: BigQuery job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-0, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} completed in state DONE
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:52 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Load job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-0, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} failed, will retry: {"errorResult":{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.","reason":"invalid"},"errors":[{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.","reason":"invalid"},{"message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0","reason":"invalid"},{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: JSON object specified for non-record field: dob","reason":"invalid"}],"state":"DONE"}
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:52 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Loading 4 files into {datasetId=com_example_gcptraining, projectId=gcp-training-246913, tableId=employee} using job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-1, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913}, attempt 1
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:53 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl startJob
INFO: Started BigQuery job: {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-1, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913}.
bq show -j --format=prettyjson --project_id=gcp-training-246913 beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-1
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:53 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Load job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-1, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} started
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:53 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl pollJob
INFO: Still waiting for BigQuery job beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-1, currently in status {"state":"RUNNING"}
bq show -j --format=prettyjson --project_id=gcp-training-246913 beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-1
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:54 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl pollJob
INFO: BigQuery job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-1, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} completed in state DONE
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:54 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Load job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-1, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} failed, will retry: {"errorResult":{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.","reason":"invalid"},"errors":[{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.","reason":"invalid"},{"message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0","reason":"invalid"},{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: JSON object specified for non-record field: dob","reason":"invalid"}],"state":"DONE"}
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:54 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Loading 4 files into {datasetId=com_example_gcptraining, projectId=gcp-training-246913, tableId=employee} using job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913}, attempt 2
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:54 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl startJob
INFO: Started BigQuery job: {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913}.
bq show -j --format=prettyjson --project_id=gcp-training-246913 beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:54 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Load job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} started
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:54 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl pollJob
INFO: Still waiting for BigQuery job beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2, currently in status {"state":"RUNNING"}
bq show -j --format=prettyjson --project_id=gcp-training-246913 beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:55 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl pollJob
INFO: BigQuery job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} completed in state DONE
Jul 21, 2019 2:02:55 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables load
INFO: Load job {jobId=beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2, location=US, projectId=gcp-training-246913} failed, will not retry: {"errorResult":{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.","reason":"invalid"},"errors":[{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.","reason":"invalid"},{"message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0","reason":"invalid"},{"location":"gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5","message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: JSON object specified for non-record field: dob","reason":"invalid"}],"state":"DONE"}
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create load job with id prefix beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000, reached max retries: 3, last failed load job: {
  "configuration" : {
    "load" : {
      "createDisposition" : "CREATE_NEVER",
      "destinationTable" : {
        "datasetId" : "com_example_gcptraining",
        "projectId" : "gcp-training-246913",
        "tableId" : "employee"
      },
      "schema" : {
        "fields" : [ {
          "mode" : "REQUIRED",
          "name" : "id",
          "type" : "INTEGER"
        }, {
          "name" : "emp_name",
          "type" : "STRING"
        }, {
          "name" : "designation",
          "type" : "STRING"
        }, {
          "name" : "dob",
          "type" : "DATE"
        }, {
          "name" : "contact_no",
          "type" : "NUMERIC"
        }, {
          "name" : "location",
          "type" : "STRING"
        }, {
          "name" : "salary",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        } ]
      },
      "sourceFormat" : "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
      "sourceUris" : [ "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/57558a8c-977e-478d-a44c-7863fb230af2", "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d73bb64e-cced-4016-9529-12df5bed8b9e", "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/be562c41-3aee-4c98-b1de-3e10691e3454", "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5" ],
      "writeDisposition" : "WRITE_APPEND"
    },
    "jobType" : "LOAD"
  },
  "etag" : "FFm2QxlI5DISFk5gFxWdbw==",
  "id" : "gcp-training-246913:US.beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2",
  "jobReference" : {
    "jobId" : "beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2",
    "location" : "US",
    "projectId" : "gcp-training-246913"
  },
  "kind" : "bigquery#job",
  "selfLink" : "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/gcp-training-246913/jobs/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2?location=US",
  "statistics" : {
    "creationTime" : "1563717774452",
    "endTime" : "1563717775186",
    "startTime" : "1563717774633"
  },
  "status" : {
    "errorResult" : {
      "location" : "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5",
      "message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    },
    "errors" : [ {
      "location" : "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5",
      "message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    }, {
      "message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    }, {
      "location" : "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5",
      "message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: JSON object specified for non-record field: dob",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    } ],
    "state" : "DONE"
  },
  "user_email" : "shubham.naphade@outlook.in"
}.
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:349)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:319)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:210)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
    at com.example.gcptraining.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create load job with id prefix beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000, reached max retries: 3, last failed load job: {
  "configuration" : {
    "load" : {
      "createDisposition" : "CREATE_NEVER",
      "destinationTable" : {
        "datasetId" : "com_example_gcptraining",
        "projectId" : "gcp-training-246913",
        "tableId" : "employee"
      },
      "schema" : {
        "fields" : [ {
          "mode" : "REQUIRED",
          "name" : "id",
          "type" : "INTEGER"
        }, {
          "name" : "emp_name",
          "type" : "STRING"
        }, {
          "name" : "designation",
          "type" : "STRING"
        }, {
          "name" : "dob",
          "type" : "DATE"
        }, {
          "name" : "contact_no",
          "type" : "NUMERIC"
        }, {
          "name" : "location",
          "type" : "STRING"
        }, {
          "name" : "salary",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        } ]
      },
      "sourceFormat" : "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
      "sourceUris" : [ "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/57558a8c-977e-478d-a44c-7863fb230af2", "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d73bb64e-cced-4016-9529-12df5bed8b9e", "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/be562c41-3aee-4c98-b1de-3e10691e3454", "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5" ],
      "writeDisposition" : "WRITE_APPEND"
    },
    "jobType" : "LOAD"
  },
  "etag" : "FFm2QxlI5DISFk5gFxWdbw==",
  "id" : "gcp-training-246913:US.beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2",
  "jobReference" : {
    "jobId" : "beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2",
    "location" : "US",
    "projectId" : "gcp-training-246913"
  },
  "kind" : "bigquery#job",
  "selfLink" : "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/gcp-training-246913/jobs/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951_0d1a010156cfb76d262315de02b986ab_00001_00000-2?location=US",
  "statistics" : {
    "creationTime" : "1563717774452",
    "endTime" : "1563717775186",
    "startTime" : "1563717774633"
  },
  "status" : {
    "errorResult" : {
      "location" : "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5",
      "message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    },
    "errors" : [ {
      "location" : "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5",
      "message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    }, {
      "message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    }, {
      "location" : "gs://com_example_gcptraining/assignment_1/temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_starterpipelineshubhamn0721140248cbe18bb0_d76616a7bafb416fa8e4ff9db0f8a951/d5c2db36-ec77-48bf-968c-e27e8c06d9c5",
      "message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: JSON object specified for non-record field: dob",
      "reason" : "invalid"
    } ],
    "state" : "DONE"
  },
  "user_email" : "shubham.naphade@outlook.in"
}.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables.load(WriteTables.java:308)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables.access$600(WriteTables.java:80)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.processElement(WriteTables.java:159)
```

Comment: Maybe you should set breakpoints in your ide to debug your code. So as to get the exact exception or you can paste your log output here. Modify your initial question and add your console log output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's a problem with your data (field dob). You're expecting a date, but for some reason it can't be store into BigQuery table.

> JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: JSON object
>   specified for non-record field: dob"

Check table schema or maybe there's a problem with the date format.

Comment: To complete the above answer, according to [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations):

"When you load CSV or JSON data, values in DATE columns must use the dash (-) separator and the date must be in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day)."
The error message indicates that you are passing a JSON object instead.